# Amazon DynamoDB and class hierarchy

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data, amazon-dynamodb

I'm working with Spring Boot and Amazon DynamoDB using [this](https://github.com/michaellavelle/spring-data-dynamodb) library. The problem is with this class hierarchy:

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "EventLogs")
abstract class AbstractEventLogEntry implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 7713867887326010287L;

  @DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName = "EventId")
  private String eventId;

  @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "GeneratedAt")
  @DynamoDBMarshalling(marshallerClass = ZonedDateTimeMarshaller.class)
  private ZonedDateTime generatedAt;

  AbstractEventLogEntry() {
    eventId = new UUID().value();
    generatedAt = ZonedDateTime.now();
  }

  /* Getters / Setter */
}
```

...another class:

```
public abstract class EventLogEntry extends AbstractEventLogEntry {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1638093418868197192L;

  @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "UserId")
  private String userId;

  @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "EventName")
  private String eventName;

  protected EventLogEntry(AdminEvent event) {
    userId = event.getUserName();
    eventName = event.getClass().getSimpleName();
  }

  protected EventLogEntry(UserEvent event) {
    userId = event.getUserId();
    eventName = event.getClass().getSimpleName();
  }

  /* Getters / Setter */
}
```

...another one:

```
public class AdminEventLogEntry extends EventLogEntry {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1953428576998278984L;

  public AdminEventLogEntry(AdminEvent event) {
    super(event);
  }
}
```

...and the last one:

```
public class UserEventLogEntry extends EventLogEntry {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 6845335344191463717L;

  public UserEventLogEntry(UserEvent event) {
    super(event);
  }
}
```

A typical class hierarchy. Now I'm trying to store `AdminEventLogEntry` and `UserEventLogEntry` using a common repository:

```
@EnableScan
public interface EventLogEntryRepository extends DynamoDBCrudRepository<EventLogEntry, String> {
  // ...
}
```

...and it always tells me:

```
com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMappingException: no key(s) present on class io.shido.events.domain.AdminEventLogEntry
```

As soon as I declare (again) the key it works:

```
@DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName = "EventId")
private String eventId;
```

So my question is: do I need to re-declared all the fields that might be common between the hierarchies? It looks like it's not recognizing the `HashKey` from the parent.

Any clues?

Comment: did you find the solution for this ?

Comment: Yes! And it's working pretty awesome (so far). I'll post it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution (some time ago), so I'm updating the post in case someone needs it along the way in the future. Notice the `abstract` class is no longer there, maybe you can tweak it for your own purposes, I didn't have time by then to test it (not now...so it's simpler, maybe not fully correct from the OOP standpoint).

The issue was with the class hierarchy and the (Spring-based) AmazonDB client's configuration. The next classes are the actual solution.

**(a) Spring config file for Amazon DynamoDB client.**

> Notice that you might not need the `dynamoDBOperationsRef` since it's
>   only used in case you need different tables "per environment". With
>   DynamoDB (if you have only one account) you can't have different
>   "environments" so you have to find a way to workaround that. This is
>   the solution: to prefix tables (and apply security settings as
>   required).

```
@Configuration
@EnableContextInstanceData // Only if you are going to use Identity and Access Management (IAM)
@EnableDynamoDBRepositories(basePackages = "io.shido.events", dynamoDBOperationsRef = "dynamoDBOperations")
class AmazonConfiguration {
  @Value("${aws.endpoint.dynamodb}")
  private String dynamoDbEndpoint;

  @Value("${ENV:local}")
  private String environment;

  @Bean
  public AmazonDynamoDB amazonDynamoDB() {
    final AmazonDynamoDBClient client = new AmazonDynamoDBClient();
    //client.setSignerRegionOverride(Regions.fromName(region).getName());
    if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(dynamoDbEndpoint)) {
      client.setEndpoint(dynamoDbEndpoint);
    }
    return client;
  }

  @Bean
  public DynamoDBOperations dynamoDBOperations() {
    final DynamoDBTemplate template = new DynamoDBTemplate(amazonDynamoDB());
    final DynamoDBMapperConfig mapperConfig = DynamoDBMapperConfig.builder()
      .withTableNameOverride(DynamoDBMapperConfig.TableNameOverride.withTableNamePrefix(environment + "-"))
      .build();
    template.setDynamoDBMapperConfig(mapperConfig);
    return template;
  }
}
```

**(b) DynamoDB annotated "entity" class**.

```
package io.shido.events;

// imports

@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "EventLogs")
final class EventLogEntry implements Serializable {
  // Define your own long serialVersionUID

  @DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName = "EventId")
  private String eventId;

  @DynamoDBTypeConvertedEnum
  @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "EventType")
  private EventType type;

  @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "EntityId")
  private String entityId;

  @Scrambled
  @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "Event")
  private Event event;

  @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "GeneratedAt")
  @DynamoDBTypeConverted(converter = ZonedDateTimeConverter.class)
  private ZonedDateTime generatedAt;

  public EventLogEntry() {
    generatedAt = ZonedDateTime.now();
  }

  public EventLogEntry(AdminEvent event) {
    this();
    eventId = event.getId();
    type = EventType.ADMIN;
    entityId = event.getEntityId();
    this.event = event;
  }

  public EventLogEntry(UserEvent event) {
    this();
    eventId = event.getId();
    type = EventType.USER;
    entityId = event.getEntityId();
    this.event = event;
  }

  // getters and setters (a MUST, at least till the version I'm using)

  // hashCode(), equals and toString()
}
```

**(c) The Spring repository definition.**

```
@EnableScan
public interface EventLogEntryRepository extends DynamoDBCrudRepository<EventLogEntry, String> { }
```

**(d) The table(s) definition.**

> Eventually, the way you define the attributes and things like that
>   it's up to you and/or your requirement(s).

```
{
  "TableName" : "local-EventLogs",
  "AttributeDefinitions" : [
    { "AttributeName" : "EventId", "AttributeType" : "S" },
    { "AttributeName" : "EventType", "AttributeType" : "S" },
    { "AttributeName" : "EntityId", "AttributeType" : "S" },
    { "AttributeName" : "Event", "AttributeType" : "S" },
    { "AttributeName" : "GeneratedAt", "AttributeType" : "S" }
  ],
  "KeySchema" : [ { "AttributeName" : "EventId", "KeyType" : "HASH" } ],
  "ProvisionedThroughput" : { "ReadCapacityUnits" : 10, "WriteCapacityUnits" : 10 }
}
```